# linux shell script variable "not found"

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, variables

Just trying to exit a loop once no input is entered at the prompt, but I'm having trouble testing for the value in an if statement?

CODE:

```
SQL="?";
while true 
do

    if [ "$SQL" == "" ]
    then
        break
    else    
        read -p "SQL: "  SQL
        clear
        php -f sql.php "$SQL"
    fi
    
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
sql.sh: 5: [: ?: unexpected operator
SQL:
```

Comment: missing blank after `[`

Comment: Thanks! I corrected that syntax and getting a new error:  unexpected operator

Comment: Do you use bash?

Comment: Linux shell script programs using the bash shell in Mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it looks like part of a scripting language, `[` is actually the name of a command, also known as `test`. The `if` statement runs that command, and acts based on its result. (The same is true, incidentally, of the `true` in your while loop - it's a command that "does nothing, successfully".)

As such, you need a space between the command and its parameters, as well as between the `if` and the command. You also need to use the correct arguments; the standard spelling for comparing two strings is `=` rather than `==`

```
if [ "$SQL" = "" ]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if test "$SQL" = ""
```